# Parsing an HTML get response

Tags: jquery, facebook, parsing

This purpose of this is to get an access token for a facebook app. I'm able to run the PHP get request and receive the following response:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
access_token=248500941859272|3ZuBwGeG8jaqxsopypAwZUIA7yQ</body>
</html>
```

I'm having difficulty parsing this response and then storing the **access_token=248500941859272|3ZuBwGeG8jaqxsopypAwZUIA7yQ** value as a string. This will then be concatenated to a URL, which will then act as my JSON feed.

I've attempted to store this value as a variable using jQuery's .get, .ajax, and .load functions, but always come up with a null result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could grab the [strip_tags() script](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535) and just run it on your text...you'll just be left with the value in between the `<body>` tags then

Comment: Cool, if it helped make sure to accept the answer so future visitors will know it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
token = "<html><head></head><body>access_token=248500941859272|3ZuBwGeG8jaqxsopypAwZUIA7yQ</body></html>";
token = token.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,""); // Strip the html tags
token = token.replace('access_token=',''); // Remove the identifier
console.log(token); // output: 248500941859272|3ZuBwGeG8jaqxsopypAwZUIA7yQ
```